# MATLAB - How to make multiple markers moving simultaneous in 3d plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, animation, markers, simultaneous

I am currently working on a project simulating the movement of two spacecraft and a moon (Phobos) around Mars. A MATLAB tool called SPICE gives me an array with the x, y and z distances and I have used these to plot the orbit which works fine. Now I want to get markers for each of the spacecraft and Phobos to see when they flyby each other. I got the markers working but not at the same time, they run after each other. I found an example on youtube so it must be possible but he has not released the code how to do it (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nArR2P0o4r4).

This is the code I have:

```
a = position_MEX_Mars(1,:);
b = position_MEX_Mars(2,:);
c = position_MEX_Mars(3,:);
k = position_MAVEN_Mars(1,:);
l = position_MAVEN_Mars(2,:);
m = position_MAVEN_Mars(3,:);
x = position_Phobos_Mars(1,:);
y = position_Phobos_Mars(2,:);
z = position_Phobos_Mars(3,:);
ah = axes;
set(ah,'XLim',[min(x) max(x)],'YLim',[min(y) max(y)],...
    'ZLim',[min(z) max(z)]);
plot3(0,0,0,'ro-',x,y,z,a,b,c,k,l,m);
grid on;
hold on;
hpoint = line('XData', 0,'YData', 0,'ZData', 0,'Color','black','Marker',...
    'o','MarkerSize',10);
ht = hgtransform('parent',ah);
set(hpoint,'Parent',ht);
for i =2:length(x)
    trans = makehgtform('translate',[x(i) y(i) z(i)]);
    set(ht,'Matrix',trans);
    pause(0.001);
end
```

This will run a nice animated plot of the trajectory of Phobos in time but only Phobos and not simultaneous with MEX and MAVEN (spacecraft from ESA and NASA).

I tried this but does not work:

```
a = position_MEX_Mars(1,:);
b = position_MEX_Mars(2,:);
c = position_MEX_Mars(3,:);
k = position_MAVEN_Mars(1,:);
l = position_MAVEN_Mars(2,:);
m = position_MAVEN_Mars(3,:);
x = position_Phobos_Mars(1,:);
y = position_Phobos_Mars(2,:);
z = position_Phobos_Mars(3,:);
ah = axes;
set(ah,'XLim',[min(x) max(x)],'YLim',[min(y) max(y)],...
    'ZLim',[min(z) max(z)]);
plot3(0,0,0,'ro-',x,y,z,a,b,c,k,l,m);
grid on;
hold on;
hpoint = line('XData', 0,'YData', 0,'ZData', 0,'Color','black','Marker',...
    'o','MarkerSize',10);
ht = hgtransform('parent',ah);
set(hpoint,'Parent',ht);
for i =2:length(x)
    trans1 = makehgtform('translate',[x(i) y(i) z(i)]);
    set(ht,'Matrix',trans1);
    trans2 = makehgtform('translate',[a(i) b(i) c(i)]);
    set(ht,'Matrix',trans2);
    pause(0.001);
end
```

I also tried merging the arrays so that it plots them each one step after each other but that makes the animation not smooth and is not satisfying for the project.

```
a = position_MEX_Mars(1,:);
b = position_MEX_Mars(2,:);
c = position_MEX_Mars(3,:);
k = position_MAVEN_Mars(1,:);
l = position_MAVEN_Mars(2,:);
m = position_MAVEN_Mars(3,:);
x = position_Phobos_Mars(1,:);
y = position_Phobos_Mars(2,:);
z = position_Phobos_Mars(3,:);
tempx = [position_MEX_Mars(1,:); position_Phobos_Mars(1,:); position_MAVEN_Mars(1,:)];
xt = tempx(:);
tempy = [position_MEX_Mars(2,:); position_Phobos_Mars(2,:); position_MAVEN_Mars(2,:)];
yt = tempy(:);
tempz = [position_MEX_Mars(3,:); position_Phobos_Mars(3,:); position_MAVEN_Mars(3,:)];
zt = tempz(:);
ah = axes;
set(ah,'XLim',[min(x) max(x)],'YLim',[min(y) max(y)],...
    'ZLim',[min(z) max(z)]);
plot3(0,0,0,'ro-',x,y,z,a,b,c,k,l,m);
grid on;
hold on;
hpoint = line('XData', 0,'YData', 0,'ZData', 0,'Color','black','Marker',...
    'o','MarkerSize',10);
ht = hgtransform('parent',ah);
set(hpoint,'Parent',ht);
for i =2:length(x)
    trans = makehgtform('translate',[xt(i) yt(i) zt(i)]);
    set(ht,'Matrix',trans);
    pause(0.001);
end
```

I think I am close but I seem to be missing something and my knowledge of MATLAB is not that great yet. I hope you can help me out.

Cheers Jeroen

Comment: It would help your question a to just trim it down to the specific problem you're trying to solve. You go on quite the orbital ramble here and I'm struggling to work out what _exactly_ you're having trouble with.

Comment: @Aiken, The problem is that i can't get two simultaneous markers moving smoothly as seen in the youtube video. The solutions I found so far show the trajectories after each other so spacecraft1 first and then spacecraft2 or for the merged array's MATLAB will switch rapedly between the spacecrafts and this is very flashy and not smooth. I hope this clears it up.

Comment: My comment was less a request for clarification in comments and more of a nudge to re-examine your question and edit to down to just the specific problem you're trying to solve. I know nothing about MATLAB and just came across your question in a review queue so I won't be able to answer your question, but if you can make it very clear to the _actual_ MATLAB experts what your problem is then it's much more likely that you (and any future visitor with the same problem) will get a satisfactory solution to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplified (and not physically correct) example that could perhaps be useful:

```
t = linspace(0,2,1000); %// time parameter
x1 = 10*cos(2*pi*t+1);
y1 = 5*sin(2*pi*t+1); %// trajectory of object 1
x2 = 2*cos(6*pi*t-2);
y2 = 3*sin(6*pi*t-2); %// trajectory of object 1
plot(x1,y1,'color',[.5 .5 .5]); %// plot trajectory of object 1
hold on
plot(x2,y2,'color',[.5 .5 .5]); %// plot trajectory of object 2
h1 = plot(x1(1),y1(1),'ro'); %// plot initial position of object 1
h2 = plot(x2(1),y2(1),'b*'); %// plot initial position of object 2
axis([-12 12 -12 12]) %// freeze axis size
grid on
for n = 1:numel(t)
    set(h1, 'XData', x1(n), 'YData', y1(n)); %// update position of object 2
    set(h2, 'XData', x2(n), 'YData', y2(n)); %// update position of object 2
    drawnow %// refresh figure
end
```

[image]

Comment: I am not trying to be rude or so, but is it not so that even if you are not doing a `drawnow`, the figure will eventually update themselves? What I mean is that since `makehgtform` seems to be slow, would `drawnow` still solve the problem then? This is the reason I did not suggest using drawnow. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks this makes it smooth but my position arrays are a.t.m. 29.000 positions longs. In my original script I used pause(0.001); to speed the animation up. This does not seem to work here are there other ways to speed the animation up?, is this what you mean @patrik?

Comment: @Terranees, my guess was that you was unable to syncroinze the different  markers. In that case I am not sure if `drawnow` would work. However, I would like to direct that question to Luis Mendo, since his solutions usually works quite well.

Comment: @patrik Actually I haven't got very deep into the question (sorry but it was too much text and code). I just wanted to show an example in which the two markers move at the same time. I use `drawnow` simply to force the update _at each loop iteration_. If you omit `drawnow`, Matlab may decide to update the figure later

Comment: @Terranees To speed the animation up, use `drawnow` instead of `pause`. That way you force the figure update without introducing any pause

Comment: @LuisMendo yeah I understand that now but that still was very slow with 28.800 positions (8 hours every second) but for the plot you dont need that many positions so I increased my for loop to steps of 100 instead of 1 and now everything works like a charm, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you tries to do is not really as easy as you think. The main issue is that you need to **update everything at the same time**. This have been implemented in several ways during the years. One way to do this is by using a so called a double buffer.

This means that you have two "surfaces" to paint on. In matlab this is translated to 2 axes (or 2 figures maybe). However, you do only have one axes visible at the same time. This means that you will have time to paint everything on the "hidden surface" before displaying the content. When you are done with everything you need you just switch which surface being visible.

It is possible that this can be done in a simpler way, but I am not familiar with the hgtransfrom functions in matlab.

**EDIT**
This is an example how it can be done

```
function test()
fig = figure;
ax1 = axes;
plot(1:10);

ax2 = axes;
plot(1:10,'r');
setVisibility(ax2,'off');

pause(1);
for k = 1:5
    setVisibility(ax2,'on');
    setVisibility(ax1,'off');
    pause(1);
    setVisibility(ax1,'on');
    setVisibility(ax2,'off');
    pause(1);
end

function setVisibility(ax, visibility)
set(ax, 'visible', visibility)
set(findall(ax), 'visible', visibility)
```

Comment: This sounds quite logical, I was wondering if you know of any examples and could you maby also mention the other ways?

Comment: @Terranees, I can post a simple example as an edit. The other ways usually requires a more advanced framework. You may also try to vectorize your code so that you can use a single call to your plot function.

Comment: If that is not to much to ask that would be great. I just started with MATLAB two weeks ago and I am used to writing out de loops and I did not know about vectorization, thanks for that tip :D @patrik

Comment: @Terranees ok, I have added the simplest of examples, which simply blinks 2 different axes. Since I found no way to set everything on the axes visible in the same function call, the full axes will not be visible at the exact same time. However, setting a plot to visible is normally a simple task, which means the eye should never notice.